# Best reference to package from any location

Tags: python, path, python-import

Let's consider very simple package with the following folder/file hierarchy:

```
package_tutorial (folder)
├── mypackage(folder)
   └── file.py
    └──__init__.py
```

I'm curious about possiblities to refer to this package from any location. I was searching for such and I found solution:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'path/to/mypackage')
import mypackage as mp
```

But is there any solution that will not force to me specify path every time I run spyder ? i.e. If I want to import `mypackage` after restarting spyder I have to rehearse code:

```
 import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'path/to/mypackage')
import mypackage as mp
```

and it's not exactly convenient for me. Preferably I want to have just

```
import mypackage as mp
```

Is there any possibility to do such from any location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the value of `sys.path` (will return a list of directories) and make sure to place your package in one of those directories so it will be in the path by default.